# How do I generate breadcrumbs for my Melt app?

Tags: php, melt-framework

I have used the Melt Framework to build a web application with the following structure:

```
/views
    /inside
        index.php
        edit.php
    /outside
        index.php
        register.php
        login.php
    layout.php
```

Now I want to generate breadcrumbs to show in the layout.php above the contents of each view. What would be the best way to implement breadcrumbs in Melt ?

Answer (score 0):

This has now been added to [solutons](https://github.com/melt/melt/wiki/Solutions).

See "Creating a breadcrumb for the menu system".